# Synaptic interface is in Japanese. How do I change to English?

Tags: language-support, synaptic

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I added Japanese as a supported language but it is not the top one and no other apps appear in Japanese. How can I get Synaptic to display in English?

Output from locale command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Here is the output from `/etc/default/locale`.

Looks like we might have found the culprit! Thank you! How do I change these values?

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ja:en_US:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of the `locale` command?

Comment: If I recall it correctly, and since Synaptic is run as root, it uses the system wide default language as denoted in `/etc/default/locale`. So can you please also show us the output of the command `cat /etc/default/locale`